# The logic of invoking virtual functions is not clear (or it is method hiding?)

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, overriding, virtual

(tested on msvc2017)

```
struct AAA
{
    virtual float run(int arg)
    {
        return 5.5f;
    }
};

struct BBB : AAA
{
    virtual bool run(double arg)
    {
        return false;
    }
};

struct CCC : BBB
{
    virtual float run(int arg)
    {
        return 7.7f;
    }

    virtual bool run(double arg)
    {
        return true;
    }
};


CCC c;
BBB* pb = &c;
pb->run(5); // call CCC::run(double arg), WHY?? 
pb->run((int)5); // call CCC::run(double arg), WHY??
```

Why does `pb->run(5)` call only `CCC::run(double arg)`, but not `CCC::run(int arg)`?

Does the virtual method of a child class with a different signature overlap the interface of the base class?

Comment: You have misconceptions about function signatures and how these are matching, that's all. Voted to close.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Close for what reason?

Comment: This is not a question about signatures having to match for the virtual method in the derived class. It's phrased confusingly, but that's not what's asked here.

Comment: I'm sure we have a few name hiding dupes though

Comment: I understand! The call works because int can be implicitly converted to double. (otherwise it would cause compilation error) If we replace AAA::run(int) and CCC::run(int) to respectively AAA::run(CustomType) and CCC::run(CustomType) - it would cause compilation error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All is simple.

The class BBB has in fact two virtual functions. One is declared in its base class AAA

```
struct AAA
{
    virtual float run(int arg)
    {
        return 5.5f;
    }
};
```

And other is declared in the class BBB itself.

```
struct BBB : AAA
{
    virtual bool run(double arg)
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

The function declared in the class BBB hides the function declared in the class AAA. (Any name declared in a derived class hides an entity with the same name declared in the base class of the derived class)

In the class CCC the both functions are overriden.

These function calls

```
pb->run(5); // call CCC::run(double arg), WHY?? 
pb->run((int)5); // call CCC::run(double arg), WHY??
```

do not differ because their arguments have the type `int`.

The static type of the pointer `pb` is `BBB *`. So the compiler searches the name run in the class BBB.

Within the class only one function with this name is visible. It is the function declared in the class

```
virtual bool run(double arg)
{
    return false;
}
```

So the compiler runs this virtual function with this signature but invokes it using the table of virtual function pointers defined for the class CCC because the dynamic type of the pointer `pb` is `CCC *`.

You could make the function declared in the class AAA visible within the class BBB by means of the `using` declaration. For example

```
struct BBB : AAA
{
    using AAA:: run;
    virtual bool run(double arg)
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

In this case the declaration of the function (declared in the class AAA) would be also a member declaration inside the class BBB. That is the class BBB will have declarations of two overloaded distinct virtual functions.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

struct AAA
{
    virtual float run(int arg)
    {
        return 5.5f;
    }
};

struct BBB : AAA
{
    using AAA:: run;
    virtual bool run(double arg)
    {
        return false;
    }
};

struct CCC : BBB
{
    virtual float run(int arg)
    {
        return 7.7f;
    }

    virtual bool run(double arg)
    {
        return true;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    CCC c;
    BBB* pb = &c;
    std::cout << pb->run(5) << '\n';
    std::cout << pb->run(5.6 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
7.7
1
```

To make the situation with the member declarations in a derived class and in its base class more clear consider a similar situation with block scopes.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

void f( int ) { std::cout << "void f( int )\n"; }
void f( double ) { std::cout << "void f( double )\n"; }

int main() 
{
    void f( double );

    f( 5 );
    f( 5.5 );

    return 0;
}
```

The inner declaration of the function `f` in the block scope of the function `main` hides the other declaration of the function in the global scope.

The program output is

```
void f( double )
void f( double )
```

Comment: >>So the compiler searches the name run in the class BBB.
Does it mean than compiler searches only by name but not with full prototype?

Comment: @dimasafo It searches the name. Then it determines that the name belongs to a function and uses the function declaration to call its corresponding definition that is overriden in the class CCC.

Answer (score 7):

When you do

```
struct BBB : AAA
{
    virtual bool run(double arg)
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

`run` has a different signature from `run` in `AAA`. This means that `BBB::run(double)` will hide `AAA::run(int)`.  Since it does, the only `run` that you can call from `BBB` is `bool run(double arg)`.  When you do

```
pb->run(5);
```

it finds `bool BBB::run(double arg)` as that is the only function you can call statically from a `BBB` and then virtual dispatch kicks in calling `CCC::run(double)`

---

In order to get the `int` version of the function to be called, you need to bring the `int` version into `BBB`.  You can do this by writing one, or you could use `using AAA::run;` to import it in.  Doing either of those will make `pb->run(5);` call the `int` version of `run` from `CCC`.

---

Don't forget, when playing with polymorphism you should declare the top level destructor (`AAA`'s in this case) to be virtual.  This allows you to delete objects correctly when using dynamic allocation.  For full details see: [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Comment: >>This means that BBB::run(double) will hide AAA::run(int)

I thought it will hide medhod only for BBB but not for CCC.
In fact it is unclear for me.

So the vtable will contain only one function. Right?

Comment: @JeJo: Through an `AAA*`, you would find `float run(int)` (and only that one, no possibility to call `bool run(double)`)

Comment: @dimasafo Can't say about that.  The reason the `int` version isn't called is because `BBB` can only call `BBB::run(double)`, so that is the fucntion that virtual dispatch happens on.  The `int` version is never considered.

Comment: @dimasafo `pb` is a `BBB`, so only `BBB`'s functions are considered.  If you change `pb` to be a `AAA*` then the `int` version is called.

Comment: @JeJo I've added that in although in this case it is not needed.

Comment: Feels like using `override` here would have helped out a lot.